# locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: vs. mapView.userLocation.location

Tags: iphone, locationmanager

For the moment, I use `mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;` for the radiating blue icon showing the iPhone's position, but do not know how to get the coordinates behind it.

I tried the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` with the configuration of `self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
 locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone; //record every movement
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

I tried either both `yourGPS=newLocation.coordinate;`
 and `yourGPS=mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;`
in the `didUpdateToLocation`, but most of the time I can see the blue bubble (controlled by the `mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;` moving ahead, but the coordinates recorded in the in the `didUpdateToLocation` are not changing.

Where should I put `yourGPS=mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;` to keep logging the coordinates driving the blue bubble please?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my app:

```
- (void)center
{
    NSLog(@"Centering...");
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    newRegion.center.longitude = mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;        
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.112872;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.109863;

    [mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;` brings memory leaks, I have stopped using it, and only use the `locationManager` to get the coordinates. The disadvantage of it is I lose the lovely blue bubble, which I do not know how to make it myself.